# Resetting formcheck for mootools on checkbox change

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a form that uses [formcheck](http://mootools.net/forge/p/formcheck) (a MooTools class that allows you to perform checks on validation) everything works fine, I have also built a part of the form that can be hidden, (by using mootools' 'slide' class) on a checkbox selection.

The problem is that the fields that are hidden are linked into the formcheck class, and are registered when the page loads via:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

var myCheck = new FormCheck('form1');
```

I have tried clearing the class on the fields when the checkbox is checked via:

```
$('auto').addEvent('click', function(e){
        if (document.getElementById("auto").checked == true) {
            myVerticalSlide.slideOut();
            document.getElementById("password").setAttribute("class", "");
```

but because it is registered at the start this doesn't have any effect, my next logial step was to recall the:

```
var myCheck = new FormCheck('form1');
```

But this then created two formchecks...

So the solution i need is to either reset the formcheck, or clear the password field from it. I hope this explains the problem, any question help welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FormCheck` documentation is quite sparing, but looking in the source code I see the functions `register` and `dispose`.

You don't need to remove the class from the input element, `dispose` will just clear its actions from the list in the `FormCheck` object, and `register` will parse the class again and add the actions:

```
$('auto').addEvent('click', function(e){
        if (document.getElementById("auto").checked == true) {
            myVerticalSlide.slideOut()
            myCheck.dispose($('password'))
        }
        else {
            myVerticalSlide.slideIn()
            myCheck.register($('password'))
        }
    })
```